# vb.net application is not working on other computers?

Tags: vb.net, shockwave, axshockwaveflash

i have a simple app of one form.
on this form there is:

webbrowser - 
axshockwavecontrol - 
combobox - 
label - 
progressbar

the code is not so much of a work so it is not neccessary to explain it.

all the problem is that the app is working perfectly on my computer but it is not working on other computers 
* on windows xp it is not opening and crashes with the "send and don't send error"
* on windows 7 the cursor is loading for a couple of seconds and nothing happen.

i don't know where to search but there is nothing so special in the application except for the shockwave control.

Comment: Impossible to debug this without seeing some code.

Comment: When it is crashing, are you seeing the UI? Are you trapping errors with a try..catch? Also, what version of the .NET framework are you targeting? Do the other computers have that installed? Do the other computers have the shockwave software installed?

Comment: does the application do anything that might require elevated permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the availability of the .Net Framework in the computer? If you don't have installers of the frameworks, you can simply download here: http://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Comment: I've never seen a *crash* as a result of not having the appropriate version of the .NET Framework installed. The app should just refuse to start. You're thinking perhaps the install is *corrupted*?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues, solutions were:

1. Make sure the latest Flash plugin is installed on the target system.
2. Compile the app and all related assemblies as "x86" (instead of "Any CPU").

Comment: I don't know, maybe the interop assemblies are 32-bits only, maybe the flash OCX doesn't like it otherwise. I don't claim to know the reason, I just know it worked for me on several occasions, and I've had the pleasure of using Flash from within .NET several times in the past years. So, no real theoretical knowledge I can share, only my experience.